# Python pandas: Multi-column filter using ~df.type.isin and !=

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a very new to python and I am learning python to automate some excels workflows for my business.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "Index": list(range(8)),
                    "Name": ["Joe", "Tom", "Joe", "Tom", "Joe", "Tom", "Joe", "Tom"],
                    "Age": [23, 54, 34, 42, 23, 54, 42, 42]})

   Index Name  Age
0      0  Joe   23
1      1  Tom   54
2      2  Joe   34
3      3  Tom   42
4      4  Joe   23
5      5  Tom   54
6      6  Joe   42
7      7  Tom   42
```

I am trying to return the data for Not "Tom" AND Not "42", that is to say I want to filter out rows 3 and 7 while keeping the rest.

I have used the following codes to try and filter out rows that are not Tom AND not 42.

```
df = df[(df.Name != "Tom") & (df.Age != 42)]

df = df[~df.Name.isin(["Tom"]) & ~df.Age.isin([42])]
```

However, the output I am getting is:

```
   Index Name  Age
0      0  Joe   23
2      2  Joe   34
4      4  Joe   23
```

However, the output I want is:

```
   Index Name  Age
0      0  Joe   23
1      1  Tom   54
2      2  Joe   34
4      4  Joe   23
5      5  Tom   54
6      6  Joe   42
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're very close to what you need.

```
df = df[~((df['Name']=='Tom') & (df['Age']==42))]

print(df)

   Index Name  Age
0      0  Joe   23
1      1  Tom   54
2      2  Joe   34
4      4  Joe   23
5      5  Tom   54
6      6  Joe   42
```

Answer (score 2):

In that case it should be Not "Tom" or Not "42"

```py
df = df[(~(df.Name=="Tom")) | (~(df.Age==42))]
print(df)
   Index Name  Age
0      0  Joe   23
1      1  Tom   54
2      2  Joe   34
4      4  Joe   23
5      5  Tom   54
6      6  Joe   42
```

Comment: alternatives : ```df.loc[(df.Name != "Tom") | (df.Age != 42)]``` or ```df.query("Name != 'Tom' or Age != 42 ")```

Comment: `df.query` is quite intuitive in such cases.